# Python converting nested for loops to comprehension for initialization

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm new to python and I'm trying to change the nested for loops I have here:

```
sumArray = [0]*len(possible[0])
for i in range(len(possible)):
    for j in range(len(possible[i])):
        sumArray[j] += possible[i][j]
```

into loop comprehension because I hear it is faster. I'm not quite sure how I should go about this since all of the tutorials I see about loop comprehension only cover initializing with a static value. Since `possible[i][j]` is not a static value and it references `i` and `j` stuff like

```
sumArray = [[sumArray[j] + possible[i][j] for i in range(len(possible))] for j in range(len(possible[i]))]
```

gives me errors about referring to i before it's defined.

Comment: If you are new to Python, maybe it is not the time to change double for loop to list complehension. It will be difficult for you to read complicated code after a week you wrote it.

Comment: I am not new to programming and I converted this over from Java where this is the only way you can do this. I can comprehend Python but there's lots of syntax nuance that I haven't really picked up. In addition, the program I have converted is too slow because I have for loops like this all over the place

Comment: If you are doing some heavy math calculations or dealing with lots of numbers in lists, it would be immensely faster to use numpy; it would be sth like `sumArray = np.sum(possible, axis=1)`.

Comment: Does your code work? What does *possible* contain? You should start by comparing *list comprehension* *vs.* iterative way (in terms of speed) on a large **unidimensional**  list, and check if it's really faster. Also, take a look at [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (mcve)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Yes my code works. `possible` is a tuple of tuples that contain possible values for rows in a grid

Answer (score 0):

`sumArray = np.sum(possible, axis=1)`

is what I was looking for. Thanks